# add css on current div if prev div has class

Tags: jquery, css

I just want to add css on current div if prev div has some class.

My html

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-1-image"></div>
<div class="views-field views-field-title"></div>
```

if div `.views-field-title` before has this div `.views-field-field-1-image` then add width on `.views-field-title` div.

Comment: add css to .views-field-field-1-image only if .views-field-field-1-image before has this .views-field-field-1-image.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html):

```
.views-field.views-field-field-1-image + .views-field.views-field-title {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-combinators) for this:

```
.views-field-field-1-image + .views-field-title {
    YOUR CSS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.views-field.views-field-field-1-image + .views-field.views-field-title {
    width: #px;
}
```

Documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors